# when I use setTimeout for show user is typing or not then its working but its blinking when I am typing continuously

Tags: reactjs, socket.io, material-ui

I am using setTimeout and its working but when I am typing continuously then also its blinking

How I can solve It ?

```
messageHandler(ev) {    
    const message = checkText(ev.target.value);
    this.setState({ message });
    let timeout;
      this.props.socket.emit('typing', true);
      timeout = setTimeout(() => {
        this.props.socket.emit('typing', false);
      }, 5000);
  }
```

```
 <TextField
              id="messageText"
              className="sendMessageTextfield"
              placeholder="Type a messsage..."
              margin="normal"
              value={this.state.message}
              variant="outlined"
              fullWidth
              multiline
              maxRows={3}
              inputProps={{ 'aria-label': 'bare', maxLength: '10000' }}
              onChange={this.messageHandler.bind(this)}
              onKeyDown={this.keyPressed.bind(this)}
            />
```

[image]

[image]
**Thanks**

Comment: It looks like you're trying to cancel the time out, but the `timeout` variable should be declared outside the function, because otherwise every time the function is called it's a new timeout variable.

Comment: this is class based component how to declare outside the function

Comment: In that case you could store timeout in `this.`